# Efficiently prime factorising an integer with an oracle

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, primes

Suppose you have a program `one_factor(N)` that, given an `n`-digit binary number, `N`, returns one of the prime factors of the number in `Theta(n^2)` time (note that I used a lowercase `n` in my theta notation.)

Using this algorithm, I want to find an efficient algorithm to factor an `n`-digit binary number into primes and print the prime factors. Moreover, I want to know how fast the algorithm runs as a function of `n`, and I also want to compute the approximate number of times my algorithm uses the `one_factor(N)` oracle in the worst case as a function of `n`.

Assume it takes `Theta(n)` time to add/divide/multiply/subtract two `n`-digit binary numbers.

---

Here is an algorithm that works:

- Call `one_factor(N)`. If the function returns `N`, then `N` is prime, and we're done. Otherwise, divide out this prime factor and store it somewhere. Repeat this procedure until we're done.

Now I'm having trouble analyzing the runtime of this procedure as a function of `n`. For simplicity, if `N` is a power of two, then `n = log_2(N)`, but I'm not really so sure how to proceed from here.

I don't understand how to find the worst-case number of times we call `one_factor`, and I'm having trouble analyzing the worst-case running time as well.

Comment: `one_factor(N)` gives you two factors, but only one of them is prime - and if you "divide out" both of them, you are just left with 1 immediately.

Comment: You divide your number with that prime, and call the oracle again with the result of that division. You keep doing that until the oracle is "exhausted".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay, that works. I just realized my first observation doesn't help due to what kaya3 said. I'm still having trouble analyzing the number of times I call this function in the worst case as a function of `n` as well as the runtime as a function of `n`. I can edit my post with my thoughts shortly.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60064522/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120327/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/46289/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 3):

First, the oracle is wonderful but slow.  So you want to try to do trial division first.

From [Arithmetic functions in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions) if you use Newton–Raphson division and the Harvey-Hoeven algorithm, checking whether you are evenly divisible by a prime `p` can be done in time `O(n log(n))`.  Computing the `O(n / log(n))` primes up to `n` is doable with the sieve of Eratosthenesin time well less than `O(n^2)`.  Doing the trial divisions can be done in time `O(n^2)`.  (Using more practical multiplication algorithms, you can do it in slightly worse time.  It won't make a difference to the overall result.)

Now you refer to your oracle.  Each oracle takes time `O(n^2)` and the division is small compared to that.  It reduces the size of the number by at least a factor of `n`.  How divisions are needed?  `O(log_n(2^n)) = O(log(2^n)/log(n)) = O(n/log(n))`.  And each division is `O(n log(n))` per the same algorithm as above.

The resulting algorithm is `O(n^2 * (n * log(n)) * n/log(n)) = O(n^4)`.  Note that the `/log(n)` is the savings from doing trial division before having to consult the oracle.

Note that you cannot improve this by doing more trial divisions because if you try to go through all of the primes up to `n^2` you have spent more time in trial division than your original algorithm and the big-O of the oracle divisions part is still the same.

Comment: Aren't you getting your `n` and `N` confused here? The number being factored is `N`, and `n` = `c*log(n)`. For example, if `N` is around `2^100` then `n` is around 100.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Nope.  You only do trial division up to `n = O(log(N))` .  Then oracle/division from there.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting there. So by doing the the trial divisions first you guarantee that each oracle invocation reduces the remaining unfactored number by factor of at least `n`, instead of just the factor of 2 you'd get by only consulting the oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that we can improve the worst case by performing trial division first. If I only want to use the oracle, then would the runtime be `O(n^2 log(n))`?

Comment: @oompa I had a big bug.  I forgot the cost of dividing by each factor.  My algorithm is `O(n^4)`.  Without trial divisions it is `O(n^4 log(n))`.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I forgot to mention that I am able to divide/add/subtract/multiply two `n`-digit binary numbers in `Theta(n)` time. I think that this drops the runtime of the algorithm without trial divisions drop to `O(n^4)`? Is that right? I still don't see where the `O(n^4)` comes from. Each call to the oracle takes `O(n^2)` time and if we require `O(n/log(n))` calls to the oracle, we would also have `n/log(n)` divisions. This would give me `O(n^2 * n/log(n) * n)` as my runtime? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @oompa I pointed to algorithms for dividing in time `O(n log(n))` time.  If you are to assume better than a `log(n)` factor disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Note that after division, your number N becomes N/2 or smaller. So you will need a maximum of log2(N) oracle invocations. This is O(n). Each invocation takes O(n²) time or less ("less" may be necessary to mention depending on your definition of O).

If your N is a power of 2, it realizes the worst case of number of invocations. By luck, it also realizes the worst case for execution time at each invocation, because during the first half of them, the number is big enough — it has at least n/2 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does this mean that the algorithm is `O(n^2 log(n))`? I think that an `n`-bit number has at most `n - 1` prime factors. I guess that means that we'll call the oracle `n - 1` times at worst?

Comment: You can make this more efficient with trial division first.

Comment: @anatolyg I realized that O(n^2 log n) is wrong. Now I think it's either O(n^3) or O(n^4). If I can divide, add, multiply, and subtract n-bit binary numbers in Theta(n) time, does that mean that this algorithm is O(n^4)? Since I need to divide out the factor on each iteration as well.

Comment: Yes, it looks like O(n^4). Not sure I can make a rigorous proof though.